# Extend Google Calendar UI with google-app-scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, add-on

I want to enhance my Google Calendar with some custom functions and I'm trying to figure out how.

Google Calendar has an Add-ons button under Settings which opens the GSuite Marketplace with the filter *compatible with calendar*.

After some googling, I found out that I could build my own GSuite apps with google-app-scripts.

So does that mean I could a write an add-on with google-app-scripts that would be *compatible with calendar* and if yes how would I set this up?

Would this enable me to directly interface with the calendar UI?
<sup>If not what would I need to do that, a Chrome Extension, a classic user-script?</sup>

Comment: Development of Calendar add-ons is currently not available to the public (only a select few - primarily vetted Google partners - have been granted access). No telling when it will be publicly available.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Ah ok, never mind then. Looks like I will have to directly highjack the calendar UI with a user-script / chrome extension or put my interface in a google-sheet... Or do both use google-sheet to do calculations on the calendar data and then grab these with a user script to display them inside the calendar... What a hackjob -.-

Comment: @DimuDesigns do you have a source for where they say it's only available to select partners? Or what would I search for to find that?

Comment: @RayB Here are a few sources: [Google Blog Announcement](https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/bring-teams-together-new-g-suite-integrations/), [G+ community thread on the topic - with comment from Eric Koleda a Technical Lead at Google for GSuite products](https://plus.google.com/+MartinHawksey/posts/gqQHDp18Afb)

Comment: @FabianN. did you manage to do it? the ui keeps autoupdating so any element i create gets removed...

Comment: @NickGinanto I ended up with a google app project containing a script that fetches the data over the google calendar api and a google spreadsheet that contains a button to run this script and print its output into the spreadsheet :-/ To get the calendar data I used `var response = Calendar.Events.list(id, args);` and for the output into the spreadshee `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Google has released the ability to build Calendar add-ons to the public! So you can now use an Apps Script project to interact with Google Calendar. https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar